# How do I format the horizontal axis labels on a line chart in the Google Visualization API?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to use the setFormattedValue() function from the DataTable class to modify the look of the labels across the horizontal axis on a line chart, but the values are not being formatted. The labels remain in their default values created by setValue().

For example, the following code does not produce 00:36:45 on the axis, but rather, just 2205.

```
var table = new google.visualization.DataTable();
table.addRows(1);

table.addColumn('number', 'time');
table.addColumn('number', 'altitude');

table.setValue(0, 0, 2205);
table.setFormattedValue(0, 0, '00:36:45');
table.setValue(0, 1, 35);

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($('chartdiv'));
chart.draw(table);
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Shouldn't setFormattedValue() cause the label to be shown as 00:36:45 instead of 2205?

If this isn't the right way to change the look of the axis labels, then how should it be done? I can't change the column type to string because the plotted line is based on numerical x/y coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You said you can't change the column type to string but, can you change it to Date? The axis is showing a number because you declared both columns as number type.

I can't see the relation between 00:36:45 and 2205. Is 2205 a value you get at that time? If you drawed more points in your line chart, you could check if their labels are the formatted value you are setting.

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution:

replace `chart.draw(table);` with:

```
chart.draw(table, {
    hAxis: {
        ticks: [
            {v:2205, f:'00:36:45'},
            {v:35, f:35}
        ]
    }
});
```

`ticks` allows you to map any value and its representation on the axis, but i think you have to list values for all labels you want. (But this could be automated by custom script)